# How to add values into array in ionic

Tags: ionic3, angular5

I've tried .concat , .push method but it doesn't work.

`showItem : any[];`

this is an array & i want to add multiple " id, name , phNo" in to this array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare array with empty array then you can use array function.

Something like this

```
  var showItem : any[] = [];

  showItem.push({
    id :'001',
    name : 'abc'
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Declare

    ShowItem:any[];

    ....

    this.ShowItem.push({

    id: ....,
    name: ...,
    phno :....

    })

    console.log(this.ShowItem);

    or 

    var array =[];


    array.push({

    id: ....,
    name: ...,
    phno :....


})

console.log(array);
```

Note: push the multiple values as objects